# Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install" at Launcher.launch in Electron build

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer

My project is a desktop Electron application that scrapes a website on click. Simple.

My project works fine locally (of course), but when I go and run `npm run package-win` and create my Windows production application, I believe the error appears when puppeteer tries to start the browser.

**I only get this when build for windows. building on my mac it works and no errors...**

```
Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"  at Launcher.launch
```

I tried deleting the package.lock, node_modules folder, and of course running `npm install` as suggested. I think it has something to do with the versioning? Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My project description.",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . my-project --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"My Project\""
  },
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^2.0.12",
    "electron-packager": "^12.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-json-storage": "^4.1.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.7",
    "puppeteer": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

I can tell my try catch is failing as the error message is from the catch so something inside this block is failing but only in the production build:

```
  async scrape(url) {
      try {
        // Launch & Setup browser
        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          args: ["--no-sandbox"],
          headless: true
        });
        this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
        await this.page.setViewport({
          width: 1920,
          height: 926
        });
        this.page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36');

        await this.page.goto(url);
        await this.page.waitForSelector('ul.rows');

        // Get all the listings on the page
        this.listings_array = await this.get_DOM_elements_from_page();
        console.log(this.listings_array);

      } catch (err) {
        console.log('SOMETHING WENT WRONG', err);
      }
    }
```

This function is inside of a class. That's why the reference to `this`. I store the browser, page, and other things on the instance of a scraper.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Mikethetechy nope :/

Comment: thanks for the reply, I got it working, I ended up moving the source code to a windows laptop then `npm install` (delete 'node_modules' before) this will install the chromium specific to windows platform in node_modules. then I was able to run my electron application that launches puppeteer's and puppeteer was able to open and run chrome :)

Comment: Oh great! I swore I tried that as well a while ago but I will have to give it another go.

Answer (score 0):

```
"pkg": "rm -rf ./pkg && pkg -t node8-macos-x64 --out-path pkg .",
"postpkg": "mkdir -p ./pkg/node_modules/puppeteer && cp -R ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium ./pkg/node_modules/puppeteer"
```

Add this to your package.json